# Complexity of many constant time steps with occasional logarithmic steps

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, amortized-analysis

I have a data structure that can perform a task $T$ in constant time, $O(1)$. However, every $k$th invocation requires $O(\log{n})$, where $k$ is constant.

Is it possible for this task to ever take amortized constant time, or is it impossible because the logarithm will eventually become greater than $k$?

If an upper bound for $n$ is known as $N$, can $k$ be chosen to be less than $\log{N}$?

Comment: It depends on how $k$ relates to $n$. For instance $k=2$ then this will not matter and $n$ operations will take $O(n \log n)$. If $k = n$ then after $n$ operations we have time $O(n + \log n)$. How does $k$ relate to $n$?

Comment: @ryan k is constant. (I have edited the question to specify this)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If every $k$th operation takes $O(\log n)$ time, then the best bound you can get on the amortized complexity is $O(1 + \frac{\log n}{k})$. This follows from the definition of amortized complexity.

Comment: Does that mean that if k is constant, the amortized complexity is O(1 + (log n / k))?

Comment: If $k$ is constant, the amortized complexity is $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus might want to note that this is per step, the overall complexity cannot be better than O(n)

Comment: Of course, I just mean the cost of the task itself.